# How does WebSockets scale compared to standard HTTP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, tcp, websocket

How does a site programmed using TCP (that is, someone on the site is connected to the server and exchanging information via TCP) scales compared to just serving information via AJAX? Say the information exchanged is the same.

Trying to clarify: I'm asking specifially about scale: I've read that keeping thousands of TCP connections is resources (which?) demanding, as compared to just serving information statically. I want to know if this correct.

Comment: Your question is kind of all over the map. You mention TCP, WebSocket, AJAX, and HTTP. What exactly are you trying to compare with what?

Comment: For what I know WebSocket is a thin layer over TCP and Ajax is just a way to make HTTP requests.

Comment: The big question is this: Does the server primarily need to push notifications of things to the client or does the client primarily need to ask the server questions? In the former case, WebSockets is much better. In the latter case, it doesn't matter very much and having fewer TCP connections can make life easier on the server.

Comment: The client does need to periodically exchange small bits of information with the server; say, three 3-words-long messages per minute per client. This is not too demanding per client; HTTP requests would work just fine. But I've been told keeping TCP connections is demanding; after 1000 or so it'll start to problem, while serving 1000 or so static files is fine. That's why I'm asking. Is that information correct?

Comment: WebSocket starts out as an HTTP connection and upgraades into a websocket, which means it allows two way communication. Are you asking if there's a benefit scalability wise of using WebSockets over standard TCP connections? The same number of connections need to be kept.

Comment: If your use case is pushing data from server to client, the comparison is meaningless. You can't do that with a "plain" HTTP request.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking. I've a feeling that HTTP is "lighter" because it just sends a file and bye, while TCP actually keeps all the connections (probably exchanging under-curtain messages for the duration?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz True, but then you have a TCP connection open anyway, so the comparison is just as moot. So I guess what I meant to say is that if you need a connection open, not having a connection open isn't an option.

Comment: @Dokkat Don't forget that a HTTP transfer also has some overhead of its own. (Request-response headers.) In the case you describe it seems like that'd be fairly significant.

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets is a technology that allows the server to push notifications to the client. AJAX on the other hand is a pull technology meaning that the client is sending requests to the server.

So for example if you had an application which needed to receive notifications from the server at regular intervals and update its UI, WebSocket is more adapted and much better. With AJAX you will have to hammer your server with requests at regular intervals to see whether some state changed on the server. With WebSockets, it's the server that will notify the client for some event happening on the server. And this will happen in a single request.

So I guess it would really depend on the type of application you are developing but WebSockets and AJAX are two completely different technologies solving different kind of problems. Which one to choose would depend on your scenario.

Comment: WebSockets and AJAX are different yes. But they are often use to solve the same problems I think.

Comment: It's true that AJAX can solve the problems that WebSockets is designed for. But it solves it in a very ineffective way. That's why WebSockets was created :-) So I wouldn't say that if you have the 2 technologies you would use them to solve the same problem at all.

Comment: Don't confuse XMLHttpRequest with AJAX.  AJAX is the generic term for the programming technique wherein browsers interact with servers while avoiding page refreshes.  This type of programming existed before XMLHttpRequest.  WebSockets certainly qualifies as AJAX style programming.  (I've never liked the term "AJAX", but it's the term that stuck.  It's better than "Web 2.0", but not as good as "Remote Scripting")

Answer (score 1):

Websockets are not a one-for-one with AJAX; they offer substantially different features. Websockets offers the ability to 'push' data to the client. AJAX works by 'pushing' data and returning a response.

The purpose of WebSockets is to provide a low-latency, bi-directional, full-duplex and long-running connection between a browser and server. WebSockets opens up possibilities with browser applications that were previously unavailable using HTTP or AJAX.

However, there is certainly an overlap in purpose between WebSockets and AJAX. For example, when the browser wants to be notified of server events (i.e. push) either AJAX or WebSockets are both viable options. If your application needs low-latency push events then this would be a factor in favor of WebSockets which would definitely scale better in this scenario. On the other hand, if you need to work with existing frameworks and deployed technologies (OAuth, RESTful API's, proxies, etc.) then AJAX is preferable.

If you don't need the specific benefits that WebSockets provides, then it's probably a better idea to stick with existing techniques like AJAX because this allows you to re-use and integrate with an existing ecosystem of tools, technologies, security mechanisms, knowledge bases that have been developed over the last 7 years.

But overall, Websockets will outperform AJAX by a significant factor.

Comment: That's all true but doesn't really address my question: I'm asking about scale: I've read that keeping thousands of TCP connections is resources (which?) demanding, as compared to just serving information statically. I want to know if this correct.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any difference when it comes to scalability between WebSockets and standards TCP connnections. WebSocket is an upgrade from a static one way pipe into a duplex one. The physical resources are the exact same.

The main advantage of WebSockets is that they run over port 80, so it avoids most firewall problems, but you have to first connect over standard HTTP.

Comment: You can run whatever you want over pot 80.  There are plenty of firewalls and similar devices doing deep packet inspection that cough on Web Sockets, just as much as they would some other protocol running on pot 80.  Fortunately, that is slowly changing as they get with the times.  All I'm trying to say is that avoiding firewall problems is not the "main advantage", and should not be a significant factor in deciding what to use, for *most* applications.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good page that clearly shows the benefits of the WebSocket API compared to Ajax long polling (especially on a large scale): http://www.websocket.org/quantum.html

It basically comes down to the fact that once the initial HTTP handshake is established, data can go back and forth much more quickly because the header overhead is greatly reduced (this is what most people refer to as bidirectional communication).

As an off note, if you only need to be able to push data from the server on a regular basis, but you don't need to make many client-initiated requests, then using [HTML5 server-sent events](http://www.websocket.org/quantum.html) with occasional Ajax requests from the client might be just what you need and much easier to implement then the WebSocket API.